# ActiveRecord search using a :belongs_to table (Rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, controller, associations, belongs-to

I have the search for a set of Listings - previous my object has been called by `@listing = Listing.last(4)`. Now I need to amend this to search by `:broker`. My problem is that `:broker` is in the `Specs` table, which `belongs_to` the `Listings` model - it's like looking for a blog post based on the comments, in a sense.

I have ActiveRecord queries that work for for Spec:

```
Spec.where(mls:"1234566")
Spec.where('broker: ( array[?] )',['%joe%','%bob%'])
Spec.distinct(:broker).limit(50).order(broker: :asc)
```

But I need to grab the associated listing, and having trouble mentally connecting the domain modelling aspect to the actual call. Could someone explain this?

Comment: You need to use `.joins` method. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

Comment: So my call might be `Listing.joins(:spec).where('broker: ( array[?] )',['%joe%','%bob%'])` ?

Comment: Yes, something like this. Maybe you will need to specify the table name: `Listing.joins(:spec).where('specs.broker ... )`

Comment: This works perfectly, I was able to use this as a jump-off point to really drill down into this search. Thanks!